# Select all elements with same id

Tags: jquery

I know that element id should be unique but which selector should be used when needed

`$("*#x1")`, `$("[id=x1]")`, or something else?

HTML

```
<div id="x1">A</div>
<div id="x1">B</div>
<div id="x2">C</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2VHBC/2/

Comment: IDs must be unique. Your HTML is invalid

Comment: @Satpal you're right but I have to deal with such environment.

Comment: Both of your examples work: http://jsfiddle.net/2VHBC/3/

Comment: can't happen . it's not valide html

Comment: Why on Earth are people up-voting this question?

Comment: use classes <div class="x1"> then $('.x1')

Comment: @RocketHazmat I know that both work, but I'm wondering which one should be preferred.

Comment: @mpapec: Neither.  This should only be used in *emergencies*!  You should switch to using classes.

Comment: @RocketHazmat tnx, now I'm aware of that (didn't know that it is such taboo among js developers).

Comment: @mpapec: It's not so much taboo as just simply incorrect.  We prefer to do things the right way versus hacking things up the wrong way.

Comment: Instead of repeating that the HTML is invalid, perhaps understand that the question may apply to a legacy or other environment where the developer has no control over the HTML, but has to work with what they have.  Answer the question, don't try to solve a problem the question is not asking about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As several other answers mentioned: **do not duplicate IDs**.  It is a terrible, horrible, no good, very bad idea: [Can multiple different HTML elements have the same ID if they're different elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-types)

I'm not sure what happens if you do this, but I'd wager it's up to the browser, which means you can't depend on it being reasonable.

Use `class` instead:

```
<div class="x1">A</div>
<div class="x1">B</div>
<div class="x2">C</div>
```

And then use jQuery's class selector, which matches the CSS syntax:

```
$('.x1')
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes your html markup is invalid and Id must be unique on the page but `attribute` selector does your work in that case.

```
alert($('[id=x1]').length);
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2VHBC/4/)

Answer (score 3):

Since ID can be accessed as any attribute `$('[id="x1"]')` will do the trick.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/VkaWN/

But if possible at all influence design change, it's bad mojo.

Answer (score 2):

This will work (Yes, it's a long shot).

```
$("[id]").each(function(){
 if($(this).attr("id")=="x1"){
  // do something
 }
});
```

ID's must be unique. If you use **class** instead of **ID**, it would have been easy to select them all.
Also, since you can select multiple elements by attribute, you can use `$('[id=x1]')`

Answer (score 1):

You should use a class to identify the wrong id used in this case.

```
console.log($('body #x1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

just add for each loop to specify all the elements having class **.one** and it will automatically turn the all elements having class **.one** to **.blue** color. Cheers! :)

```
   let clonedEle = $(".one").clone();

    clonedEle.insertAfter(".one");

    $(".one").click(function() {
      $(".one").each(function(){
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Always us different id. Simply add custom attribute on your div and the try doing like below:

```
<div data-id='x1' id='div1'></div>
<div data-id='x1' id='div2'></div>
<div data-id='x2' id='div3'></div>

var number = 6;
var myDiv = $('div[data-id='x1']');
```